# How to hide scrollbar in laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel-5.8

I use Argon Laravel Frontend Preset. I like it but the scrollbar seems not match in the template itself. The Argon use default scrollbar I think  and I didn't like it. I want it to be invisible. I don't how, I did some code but it didn't work.

```
//_custom.scss

 html  { 
     overflow-x: hidden !important;
  }


//app.scss

@import 'custom';
```

Comment: With `overflow: hidden;` you disable scroll all along. That's not what you want i guess?

Comment: I wanted only to hide the scrollbar itself without disabling scrolling upside down.

Comment: I presume that I can scroll the page upside down without the scrollbar.

Comment: You should look for the container that has the scrolling on it. Instead of the `html` or `body` tags it could be some element with a `wrapper` or `container` class on it. This page could help you with hiding the scrollbars but still be able to scroll: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kurlak/2013/11/03/hiding-vertical-scrollbars-with-pure-css-in-chrome-ie-6-firefox-opera-and-safari/